# What is the probability that he gets at least one mail in each day?

Tags: probability

If someone gets $13$ mails over the period of $5$ weekdays. What is the probability that he gets at least one mail in each day?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: We need information about how the $13$ mails are distributed over the $5$ weekdays in order to answer the question.

Comment: he is getting mails randomly.

Comment: @user1816574: "randomly" doesn't determine a distribution. If there's a probability $\frac12$ of receiving a mail on the first day and a probability $\frac12$ of receiving a mail on the last day, that's also "getting mails randomly". Do you mean that each mail arrives independently of all other mails, and with equal probability on any of the $5$ weekdays?

Comment: yes. each mail arrives independently with equal probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT - I would say:

If number of solutions of the equation $i_1+i_2+i_3+i_4+i_5 = 13$

- where $i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4,i_5\in (1,2,3,\cdots,13) = \omega$,
- where $i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4,i_5\in (0,1,2,3,\cdots,13) = \Omega$

then the sought probability $P=\frac{\omega}{\Omega}$

[I would say: $\quad \omega=495,\quad \Omega=2380$]

Answer (score 0):

this is same as counting number of onto functions from set A which has 13 elements defined to set B which has 5 elements. sample space is 5^13.
to count favourable points, you need to 
1. group 13  elements into 5 groups such that none is empty
like (9,1,1,1,1).... (6,3,2,1,1) and so on. now distrbite them to 5 elements of B.